# dynamic text change in react-native

Tags: react-native

Hi I am looking for the solution to change text dynamically.
I am writing code to show processing results on screen.

After some googling, I found there is a code to update text dynamically as follows.

But I would like to update text without any internal event. I want to change text from outside of the class. But I don't know how to implement it as I am a javascript and react-native beginner. There are other classes to process some functions so that I need to show the updated results using Results class which is an another component of the screen.

How can I deliver 'result' to Results class and how to update it dynamically and automatically?

```
class Results extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
           log: 'Processing results'
        }
    }

    updateText = (result) => {
        this.setState({log: result})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text onPress = {this.updateText}>
                    {this.state.log}
                </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to me that `props` can solve your problem.

Basically when you try to render `Results` class, pass along the value as a `prop` like below:

```
<Results dynamicText='HI' />
```

Then, from your `Results` class, access this external value via `this.props.dynamicText` as below

```
class Results extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>
                {this.props.dynamicText}
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Isaac, thank you for your answer. I would like to change the text from another class or function in another class. This is for dynamic change from View of return part. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Issac answered, you can also hook up your current class to Redux and dispatch actions from another class to force state changes.

React Native and ReactJS has a different concept of how classes *react* to each other. Most other languages use inheritance based interactions to affect changes in classes other than itself. React itself is more composition based where changing the value/state/variable of one class requires either a state change or a prop change. The caveat to that us using Redux, which utilizes an overarching Store where any component that's connected to it can pull values or dispatch actions to change values.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not using Redux at the moment, but let me check it.

Comment: If you don't want to use Redux, then passing it as props would be the best alternative, but if the data you are changing and way you are changing it are too far nested, then it gets very complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Let me research/study about Redux!